# Is it possible to search for files on all partitions at the same time?

Tags: partitioning

On Ubuntu, is there any way to search for files on multiple hard disk partitions at once? I'd like to search the contents of all of my hard disk partitions at the same time, including my Windows partition and my Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 4):

All your hard discs are mounted somewhere (most likely under `/media` or otherwise under `/mnt`) so if you use `find` from command line at root level (`/`) or navigate to root level in Nautilus it will include your USB discs if they are mounted.

Linux can read NTFS so if you mounted the disc (example: `mount -tntfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt`) it will also search that disc.

[The online manpage for find you can find here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/find.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can execute command 'find' in differnet terminal windows at the same time and giving location of each partition to each different find command.

see `man find` for details.

Comment: Do you mean that I should simply type the command separately into 3 different terminal windows, instead of using a single command to search within each partition at the same time?

Comment: BTW, how many pages long is `man find`?

Comment: this answser would be better if it included a bash script to replace the manual work.